# How to convert flat key-value file to a bean object dynamically?

Tags: java, mapping

I'd like to convert a flat file with many different keys to a java bean dto, as follows:

Flat file:

```
mykey=example
anotherkey=test
adress-street-1=downtown street
address-town-1=nyc
address-stree-2=some street
adrerss-town-2=los angeles
```

Target bean:

```
public class Content {
    private String mykey;
    private String anotherkey;
    private List<Address> address;
}

public class Address {
    private String street,
    private String town;    
}
```

Question: how could I achieve the mapping between the flat file and the target bean? Imagine a few hundred property keys. Some may occur multiple times, in whose cases they and with an index number, like `address-town-1`.

```
Content content = new Content();

while(true) {
   String line = reader.readLine();
   String key = line.split("=")[0];
   String value = line.split("=")[1];

   switch(key) {
      case "mykey": content.setMykey(value);
      case "anotherkey": content.setAnotherkey(value);
      ...
   }
}
```

But I would have to code those mappings a few hundred times, which does not feel right.

**Question:** is there a better way, eg by using some kind of xml configuration/mapping file, and reflection?

`BeanIO` comes close to what I want to achieve. But it lacks the ability to just convert multiple different fields to the bean field name. And also it cannot group sets like the `address-*` example into a `List`.

Is there any known library or concept that I could use? Some framework that could do the formatting, using eg a xml configuration file?

Or would I have to write my own parser and use reflection to write the data to my java objects?

Comment: You can use Jackson to convert from a key/value map to your bean.

Comment: Could you give a code example based on my sample data?

Comment: `new ObjectMapper().convertValue(map, Content.class)`